# GeoServer export DXF with colors and labels

Tags: geoserver, dxf

I have GeoServer 2.15.1 with the DXF export plugin installed and I would like to export my layers with the colors and labels shown on the GeoServer.

When I export all layers of both line and polygon types are drawn as a line and in white

In a blog post geosolutions mentions the possibility of an advanced configuration where it is possible to choose colors and labels.

https://www.geosolutionsgroup.com/blog/developers-corner-dxf-output-format-promoted-to-official-extension-for-geoserver/

Where are the color and label options for DXF file export configured?

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: what URL are you requesting?

Comment: I accessed it through the link on the layer preview page which looks something like this ... http://xxx.yyy.br/geoserver/Ceara/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=Ceara%3Abairros_a&maxFeatures=5000&outputFormat=DXF&PropertyName=(bairros)